# A text node cannot be a child of a <View>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to create a table using **ReactJS**, so this is the code I found :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  RefreshControl,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Table extends Component {
    renderRow() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }} /> { /* Edit these as they are your cells. You may even take parameters to display different data / react elements etc. */}
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }} />
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            {
                data.map((datum) => { // This will render a row for each data element.
                    return this.renderRow();
                })
            }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

but I got an error saying `A text node cannot be a child of a <View>`, I don't understand because there is no `<Text>` element in `<View>` and loop looks like valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that if you remove the comment inside the `renderRow()` it works just fine:

```
// Remove this comment
 { /* Edit these as they are your cells. You may even take parameters to display different data / react elements etc. */}
```

Maybe RN sees that as a plain text insted of a comment.

Comment: Are there any updates about this in terms of why this is even detected to be 'Text' by React Native? Is it just better to wrap your comments in a `<Text></Text>`?

Answer (score 2):

**Correct way of commenting in react is like this:**

```
{/* your comment goes here*/}
```

when you are commenting with `//`,react will treat this as a text node.
As well as react native docs mentions ,we cannot wrap text with `<View>` .

the **correct way** is :

```
<View>
   <Text>
     dummy text
   </Text>
</View>
```

**wrong way :**

```
<View>
     dummy text
</View>
```

[Check react native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.64/text)